# Microdata markup - do I add to EACH markup reference?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I have a resource which ranks #1 on the web for conference listing. I've discovered and been advised to add Microdata markup since it does no harm and if anything it helps search engines understand how my data is presented...

The code below shows the tags correctly inserted as per the Google Wizard tool here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/

I have several hundred of these `<li>` an event is placed in here `</li>` tags that list each of the events.

My question  is, do I include the reference to the `<li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">` in each event? Seems a bit overkill to call the URL 200+ times?

The below is an example of ONE event, should they all be 100% the same as this?

```
                                            <!-- Microdata markup added by Google Structured Data Markup Helper. -->
                    <li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
                        <a class="expand">
                        <div class="right-arrow">
                            +
                        </div>
                        <h2 itemprop="name" class="events">2016 Small Business Cyber Security Conference</h2><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span><span itemprop="startDate" content="2016-02-10" class="eventdate">February 10, 2016</span> | 
                        <span itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
                        <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                        <span itemprop="streetAddress">New York, New York,</span> 
                        <span itemprop="addressCountry">USA</span></span></span></a>
                        <div class="detail">
                            <div id="left" style="width:15%;float:left;height:100%;">
                                <div id="sup"><img itemprop="image" class="img-responsive hidden-xs" src="http://concise.education/conference.new/logo.png" width="100%"/></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="right" style="width:85%;float:right;height:100%;padding-left:20px;">
                                <div id="sup">
                                    <div>

                            <span itemprop="description"><strong>Cyber Conference Overview:</strong><br/>
                            Description here....</span><br/>
                            <br/>
                            <a itemprop="url" href="http://events.constantcontact.com/register/event?llr=rzxqjaeab&oeidk=a07ec4cebsk3fabf91a">Visit Website</a><!--   <span class="twitterbox hidden-xs">@twitter</span>  -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

++++++

In other words, must each event start with `<li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">`

Answer (score 2):

The important thing is to understand that when writing a tag like the one in the example `<li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">` that URL is not being *called*, you are providing meta information to help search engines to understand your content better.

All your events should be declared that way, so each event is correctly parsed and understood by Search Engines

Answer (score 0):

[marcanuy’s answer is correct](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98405/17633), the URL in `itemtype` doesn’t get visited (at least not in the typical case). Consumers that support the vocabulary Schema.org know as soon as they see `http://schema.org/Event` that it’s an event.

If you think it’s too much overhead to repeat the URL 200 times, you can consider using [RDFa (Lite)](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/) instead of Microdata. It allows you to define Schema.org as default vocabulary (e.g. on the `html` or `body` element) and then to use `Event` instead of `http://schema.org/Event` for each event:

```html
<!-- RDFa (Lite) -->

<body vocab="http://schema.org/">
  <ul>
    <li typeof="Event"></li>
    <li typeof="Event"></li>
    <li typeof="Event"></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

For comparison, the same in Microdata:

```
<!-- Microdata -->

<body>
  <ul>
    <li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"></li>
    <li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"></li>
    <li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

So in RDFa you have to use `typeof` instead of `itemtype` (and there is no need for `itemscope`), and `property` instead of `itemprop`.